# Dynamically created blocks: layout->createBlock() or blockFactory->create()?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento-2.1, dependency-injection

I want to create a block dynamically but not render it within the layout hierarchy (I am going to save the output).

Is there any reason to use `Layout::createBlock()` in this case or can I instantiate it directly with a factory? Or even inject the block itself as shared instance into the class where I'm using it?

I would prefer to avoiding the unnecessary dependency to the layout and the additional abstraction but I am not sure what might break if the block is not associated to the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't do it via `Layout::createBlock` some of the methods you might call from that block will throw exceptions or return an empty string.
Here are some examples (all of them from `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock`):

- getChildNames
- setChild
- addChild
- unsetChild
- unsetChildren
- getChildBlock
- getChildHtml
- getChildChildHtml
- getBlockHtml
- insert
- append
- getGroupChildNames

I would advice to use the `createBlock` if you want to be politically correct, but if you don't need any of the methods above I see no harm in using the block as a shared instance.

Comment: I found out that the block still has access to the layout because it is passed on construction via context object, but after checking "addChild" and related methods, I understand that they throw exceptions because `$this->_nameInLayout` is empty. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

`Layout::createBlock()` is useful if the block is a CMS block or page that has `{{...}}` content such as widgets or variables. If you don't go through the layout, you won't get these elements.